Help regarding propositional statement simplification
I have a compound propositional statement
$$(p\vee q\vee r)\wedge(p\vee t\vee\neg q)\wedge(p\vee \neg t\vee r) $$
I have been asked to simplify it using boolean algebra manipulation and rules of propositional logic
I have been trying to this for previous 1 hour. Although i can do it using K-maps , i feel like there is an easy and simple algebraic manipulation which i am unable to see.
If anyone knows how to do it succinctly using propositional logic laws or boolean algebra , i would be very grateful if they could share it with me.

This answer corresponds to Anne's, except that it goes step by step through the logical rearrangements so you see how to arrive at the answer algebraically. The key steps are two factorings ($p$ then $r$) then a negation to cause a term to become irrelevant $\lnot(t \lor \lnot q$)
$(p \lor q \lor r) \land (p \lor t \lor \lnot q) \land (p \lor \lnot t \lor r)$
$p \lor [(q \lor r) \land (t \lor \lnot q) \land ( \lnot t \lor r)]$
$p \lor [(r \lor q) \land (r \lor \lnot t) \land (t \lor \lnot q)]$
$p \lor [(r \lor (q \land \lnot t))\land (t \lor \lnot q)]$
$p \lor [(r \lor \lnot(\lnot q \lor t))\land (t \lor \lnot q)]$
$p \lor [(r \lor \lnot(t \lor \lnot q))\land (t \lor \lnot q)]$
$p \lor [r \land (t \lor \lnot q)]$

Thanks a lot for the explanation @RobinSparrow. I had a problem understanding the last 2 steps. Shouldn't $ \lnot(t\lor \lnot q)\land(t\lor \lnot q)=r$ ? proceedings which , shouldn't the final answer be only $p \lor r$ ?

@AnneBauval what I meant is our answers are the same, at the time you had not actually stated the answer, and I suspected (correctly) that the OP would not track your logic.

@Dhruv - perhaps your confusion stemmed from the missing close parentheses that Anne fixed in her edit. The point is that the final portion "AND (t OR (NOT q))" must be true due to the AND, so the negation of (t OR (NOT q)) in the previous portion can never be true and becomes irrelevant, so we may omit it.

Thank you, now I understand: you answer was the same, not the method (which the OP also has difficulties to follow).

@Dhruv $r\lor(\lnot v\land v)$ would indeed be equivalent to $r$, but $(r\lor\lnot v)\land v$ is equivalent to $r\land v$. (Here, $v$ stands for $t\lor\lnot q$.)

Thanks a lot. This was a silly oversight on my part

First, the statement you want to simplify is equivalent to $p\lor s$, where
$$s:=[(q\lor r)\land(q\to t)\land(t\to r)].$$
Then, notice that $s$ implies $r$. Since, in turn, $r$ implies the first and third terms of the conjuction $s$ (i.e. $q\lor r$ and $t\to r$), $s$ is therefore equivalent to
$$r\land(q\to t),$$
hence the original statement is equivalent to
$$p\lor[r\land(q\to t)].$$

Thanks a lot for your time. I am having trouble understanding the last part. Since (qVr)^(q→t)^(t→r)→r . Shouldn't the answer be pVr? Can you please elaborate a bit more as to why the final answer is pV(r^(q→t)?

Does the edit suffice? $s$ implies $r$ but is not equivalent to it, since $r$ does not imply the second term $q\to t$ of the conjunction $s$.

I am really sorry but i am not able to follow along. I assume you mean $r→(q \lor r) \land (t→ r)$ when you say that r implies first and third terms of the conjunction. I am not able to understand how r implies these terms and how are they reduced to $r \land (q→t) $.

$r⊢ q\lor r$ is obvious, and similarly, so is $r⊢(\neg t)\lor r$. So, $r⊢u$, where $u:=(q\lor r)\land(t\to r)$. Therefore, $r\land(q\to t)⊢s$ (where $s$ was defined as $u\land(q\to t)$). Conversely, $s⊢r\land(q\to t)$, since $s⊢r$ and $s⊢q\to t$.

You are welcome. I'd prefer you to post your own answer.

This is the same answer with same method as @AnneBauval.I have just elaborated it with step by step explanations to make it easier for others to understand.
$$(p∨q∨r)∧(p∨t∨¬q)∧(p∨¬t∨r)\\
  p∨[(q∨r)∧(t∨¬q)∧(¬t∨r)]$$.
Now , using the logical equivalence $\lnot p \lor q \equiv p\implies q$,
we do, $(t∨¬q) \equiv (\lnot q \lor t) \equiv (q\implies t) and (¬t∨r) \equiv (t \implies r)$.
Using these , the equation reduces to :
$$p\lor [(q∨r)∧(q\implies t)∧(t \implies r)]$$.
Let's take s:=$[(q∨r)∧(q\implies t)∧(t \implies r)]$.
PART 1
Using hypothetical syllogism: $[(q\implies t)∧(t \implies r)]\implies (q \implies r) \equiv (\lnot q \lor r)$ and,
using resolution : $[(\lnot q \lor r) \land (q∨r)]\implies r$
Thus , $s \implies r$
Also,  $s \implies (q \implies t)$ (By Simplification rule)
By using the identity $(p \implies q) \land (p \implies r) \equiv (p \implies (q \land r))$, we get
$$s \implies (r \land (q \implies t)) . . . . . . . (eq.1)$$
PART 2
Using Addition law of inference: $$r \implies q \lor r,\\
r \implies r \lor \lnot t \equiv \lnot t \lor r \equiv (t\implies r)$$
Thus, we see :
$$r \land (q \implies t)\implies s   . . . . . .(eq. 2)$$
FINALLY , After combining eq.1 and eq.2 we get,
$$s \iff (r \land (q \implies t))   i.e. \\
s \equiv (r \land (q \implies t))$$
Hence, the reduced equation comes out to be :
$$p \lor s
\\p \lor [r \land (q \implies t)]$$
